# CSS Designing Issue with UL and LI

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue regarding the CSS while applying to the UL and LI Tag in HTML UI designing.

My CSS Code

```css
.jobs {
  list-style: none;
}

.jobs li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jobs::after {
  content: "";
  display: grid;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="jobs">

    <div th:each="indTypeProduct :${indTypeProducts}">

        <li>

            <div class="card" id="wrapper" style="align-items: center;">

                <a href="#"><p th:text="${indTypeProduct}" /></a>

            </div>
        </li>
         <br>
    </div>
</ul>
```

[image]

Could you please anyone help me on this issue?

Check the view source

Updated Code Please have a look and let me know where I'm going wrong and let me know, I simply want all my result should be align and have in same line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<style type="text/css">

#wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.card a {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
 
.jobs {
    list-style: none;
}

.jobs li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.jobs::after {
    content: "";
    display: grid;
    clear: both;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">Cart Studio</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/product">Product</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"
                    placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h4>
            <p style="margin-left: 15px"> Hello test@gmail.com Greetings!!</p>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <hr style="color: black;">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide"
        data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"
                class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/uploads/images.jpg"
                    alt="First 1 slide" width="100" height="350">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/uploads/images.jpg"
                    width="100" height="350" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/uploads/images.jpg"
                    width="300" height="350" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span
            class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span
            class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            role="button" data-slide="next"> <span
            class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span
            class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <hr style="color: black;">

    <ul class="jobs">

        <div>

            <li>

                <div class="card" id="wrapper" style="align-items: center;">

                    <!-- <img th:src="@{/images/Mobile-Phones-Category.jpg}" alt="category" width="150" height="150"> -->

                    <a href="#"><p >retail</p></a>

                </div>
            </li>
             <br>
        </div>

        <div>

            <li>

                <div class="card" id="wrapper" style="align-items: center;">

                    <!-- <img th:src="@{/images/Mobile-Phones-Category.jpg}" alt="category" width="150" height="150"> -->

                    <a href="#"><p >mobile</p></a>

                </div>
            </li>
             <br>
        </div>
    </ul>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For a start your HTML is invalid. UL can only contain li as direct children

Comment: @Paulie_D, No, that's not true. Even Google will wrap the `<li>` inside an `<a>` to make the whole a link on some websites.

Comment: google is not god, check it yourself from official reference : https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Manjuboyz please check the attached image

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, neat to know.

Comment: can anyone answer instead of teaching each other because my code is working I only need to make my result in proper align not like one is above and the other is going down. it should be the same as the first one. (Refer attached image)

Comment: you should share the html generated, (view source), maybe it will  clearly show the structure generated which CSS  tries to style ;) At least to reproduce your issue from your snippet

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Please remove the java tag.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I have added Please check

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have added here `<ul class="row" style="width: 400px">` and it fixed the issue and width for not getting horizonatl scroll bar.